# How to use 'refs' in mogoose properly?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have 3 schema as per
This one is customer

```
    const customerSchema = {
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    products:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Products'
    }],

    salesExcecutive:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Sales'
    }]


}

const Customer = mongoose.model('Customer', customerSchema)
```

This is Product

```
const productSchema = {
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    customer:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Customer'
    }],

    salesExcecutive:[{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Sales'
    }]


}

const Product = mongoose.model('Product', productSchema)
```

And this is Sales

```
const salesSchema = {
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    product:{
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'  
    },
    customer:{
        type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref:"Customer"
    }
}

const Sale = mongoose.model('Sale',salesSchema)
```

As you can see I have used 'refs' and want to connect all 3 of these with each other, if a user is saving product, sales, and customer simultaneously, it should go in each other, like from any of these 3 I can access the current information.

I tried using refs

```
router.post('/add',verify,async (req,res)=>{
    var customerName =  req.body.customer;
    var productName = req.body.product;
    var saleName = req.body.sale


    const cust = new customer({
        name:customerName,

    })

    const prod = new product({
        name:productName
    })

    const sale = new sales({
        name:saleName
    })

    res.send(cust._id+" "+prod._id+" "+sale._id)
})
```

Now this is what I have, for now, I have all 3 ids, but how do I save it in each one of them, or is there a simpler method or I am doing something wrong

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below:

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
router.post('/add',verify,async (req,res)=>{
    var customerName =  req.body.customer;
    var productName = req.body.product;
    var saleName = req.body.sale

    let custId=mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    let prodId=mongoose.Types.ObjectId();
    let saleId=mongoose.Types.ObjectId();

    const cust = new customer({
        _id:custId,
        name:customerName,
        products:[prodId],
        salesExcecutive:[saleId]

    })

    const prod = new product({
        _id:prodId
        name:productName,
        customer:[custId],
        salesExcecutive:[saleId]
    })

    const sale = new sales({
        _id:saleId,
        name:saleName,
        customer:custId,
        product:prodId
    })

    res.send(custId+" "+prodId+" "+saleId)
})
```

Comment: Thanks let me check

Comment: So basically mongoose.Types.ObjectId(); will generate the id beforehand, i can populate it right ?

Comment: yes you can populate it as it's already saved in other collection while saving.

Comment: Thanks thats great